# Cisco ASA VPN SLA to ping Hostname

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, cisco-asa

We have set up VPN with a client using a Cisco ASA on their end, and an Amazon Web Services solution on our end.  Configured is an SLA Monitor which pings an instance within our subnet to generate interesting traffic and keep the tunnel alive.

Due to the dynamic nature of our servers in AWS, we would like to instead configure the SLA Monitor to ping a *hostname* instead of an *IP address*.

Our current configuration is doing this:

```
sla monitor 1
   type echo protocol ipIcmpEcho <INSTANCE_PRIVATE_IP> interface <OUTSIDE_INTERFACE>
   frequency 5
exit

sla monitor schedule 1 life forever start-time now
```

We would like to replace `<INSTANCE_PRIVATE_IP>` with a hostname, however our client has informed us that the hostname would not resolve.

**Is there a way to achieve this, and target a hostname instead of an IP address?**

Comment: Have you considered using the public dns name of an ec2 instance?

Comment: Yes.  Plan to use public DNS of elastic load balancer actually.  Will Cisco ASA natively support DNS resolution if it is simply specified instead of `INSTANCE_PRIVATE_IP`?

Comment: Can't help with that part sorry. Suggest you read documentation or give it a go.

Comment: Thank-you.  Can't find anything straightforward in documentation; wanted to verify as a possibility before instructing our client to make config changes.